# pg_dump's custom format creates errors the plain format doesn't have

Tags: postgresql

I've pored through the documentation of pg_dump and pg_restore and haven't found anything that would indicate that the custom format is more restrictive in some way. In fact, everything seems to indicate the opposite.

I'm running pg_dump like:

```
pg_dump --host=example.com --username=xxx --dbname=xxx \
     --format=plain --table=ns_* --data-only > dump
```

And restoring that with:

```
cat dump | psql --host=example.com --username=xxx --dbname=xxx
```

And that that works fine. No errors and the data looks completely as expected. But if I change pg_dump to use the custom syntax like so:

```
pg_dump --host=example.com --username=xxx --dbname=xxx \
     --format=custom --table=ns_* --data-only > dump
```

And then restore with:

```
pg_restore --host=example.com --username=xxx --dbname=xxx \
    --data-only --single-transaction dump
```

I get the error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2210; 0 1440417 TABLE DATA <table_name> <database_name>
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "<table_name>": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "<table_name>_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (ex_id)=(7) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY <table_name>, line 1
```

I don't see why this error occurs. First and foremost, it doesn't make any sense because there's obviously no duplicate key, otherwise the regular insertion would have failed (and manual inspection confirms this).

The database I'm inserting into is empty. It's been initialized with the schema (same schema that we're dumping from) and that's it.

Perhaps of note is that the primary keys have been modified in the past. They were all incremented by a set number, which required removing the primary key constraint temporarily. But this shouldn't invalidate the data (and the fact that the plain text format works shows the data is valid).

Comment: That's really weird. It looks like `pg_restore` is perhaps restoring `<table_name>` twice.

Comment: Could you drop the primary key (just for a test) and then use pg_restore on an empty table? Does it work and do you see any problems with not so unique values that should have been unique?

Comment: did you try adding --compress=4 to your pg_dump ? afaik custom mode needs compression.